# In perl, what does $" mean? Does it just mean a space?

Tags: perl

I saw the following line of code:

```
my $t = $" x 1;
```

What does `$"` mean here? Is it just a space?

I've tested it, and it seems like a space. But I don't know why they use $" instead of `$" "` or `" "`. Who knows that?

Comment: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=353259

Comment: `$" "` is a syntax error

Comment: Note: `my $t = $" x 1;` can be simplified to `my $t = $";` unless you want to force stringification.

Comment: What kept you from looking it up in the manual?

Comment: @reinierpost I don't know what kept Shimmey, but I find it difficult to look up things with names like `$"`. General purpose search engines don't work too well with that. :-)

Comment: @Thilo: So if you can't google for it there's no way to find it? How very modern.

Comment: True, but just [Googling for `perl variable`](https://www.google.nl/search?hl=en&q=perl+variable) produces the relevant manual page as the first hit, at least for me.

Answer (score 5):

From [`perldoc perlvar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html):

```
   $LIST_SEPARATOR
   $"      When an array or an array slice is interpolated into a double-
           quoted string or a similar context such as "/.../", its
           elements are separated by this value.  Default is a space.
```

So, yes, by default it is a space, but one could change that.

> I don't know why they use $" instead of $" " or " ".

You would output `$"` instead of just a literal space if you want to allow the user to configure what the separator should be.

In that code, you can do `local $" = ','` before calling the subroutine and it will use commas instead of spaces between the elements.

Answer (score 2):

It's a variable named `$"`. It contains a space by default. It's the value used when an array is interpolated into a string. See [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your answers! They are very helpful for me.
Here I found a web page containing perl special variables:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_special_variables.htm